# HTML String break

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
    <div style='width:40%'>

       <p> "First Name1 " + FirstName1 + " Last Name1 " + LastName1 + " First Name2 " + FirstName2 + " Last Name2 " + LastName2 + "First Name3 " + FirstName3 + " Last Name3 " + LastName3 .... </p>

    </div>
```

Note that the code I have is generated with a program but HTML code nevertheless. 
What happens in the code I have above is that once the text extends beyond 40% it continues on the next line but broken in between First Name and Last Name at times. . What I like to happen is that it should break at the next First Name versus somewhere in between the First Name and Last Name.

As such, I like to keep the First Name and Last Name on the same line without any breaks in between which happens at times. I tried &nbsp but that did not fix the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try putting `&nbsp;` between the first and last name (instead of a space).

Comment: Please show a real example and specify exactly where line breaks are to be permitted.

Comment: If this is really just about preventing line breaks within segments of text, there are surely existing questions with good answers, explaining the alternative techniques, at SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple options -- you can use a non-breaking space with the code `&nbsp;` rather than a regular space following your first name.

OR you can wrap your first/last name inside a `span` tag and give that span a CSS property of `whitespace: nowrap`:

HTML:

```
<span class="no-wrap">Firstname Lastname</span>
```

CSS:

```
.no-wrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<br />`

```
<div style='width:40%'>

       <p> "First Name1 " + FirstName1 + "Last Name1" + LastName1 + "<br />First Name2 " + FirstName2 + "Last Name2" + LastName2 + "<br />First Name3 " + FirstName3 + "Last Name3" + LastName3 .... </p>

    </div>
```